# Загрузка картинки с помощью OpenCV по указателю

Tags: c++, opencv, c++14

Суть вопроса: Подскажите пожалуйста как загрузить картинку в OpenCV по указателю.

Входные данные: указатель на изображение

Необходимые выходные данные: cv::Mat изображение

Пояснение: можно сделать так(ниже), если картинка лежит в директории;

```
String imageName("C:/Images/1.jpg");
Mat image;
image = imread(samples::findFile(imageName), IMREAD_COLOR);
```

Мне нужно получить аналогичный результат, но только с указателем на картинку вместо дирректорией.

Заранее спасибо за внимаение к моему вопросу:)

Comment: что подразумевается под `указатель на картинку`?

Comment: да ну, не может быть чтобы на данные!!! Ну а если серьезно: а на какие данные? Это массив пикселей или содержимое файла изображения? Для них используются разные способы (не говоря ужу о том, что и данные сами по себе разные)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае поможет этот конструктор:

```
Mat (int rows, int cols, int type, void *data, size_t step=AUTO_STEP)
```

Мой пример:

```
Mat(imVA.rows, imVA.cols, CV_8UC3, *imVA.ptr, imVA.step);
```